# Calling a method from a class in Java

Tags: java, public, void

Basically, I am making a gambling game. It asks the person how much they want to bet, then if they are right, their 'wallet' increases by however much they win back, depending on the odds given. I am using a class exclusively for the persons 'wallet'.

```java
public class Wallet {

    private double cash;

    public Wallet() {cash=0.0;}

    public void put(double money) {
        assert money > 0 : "Die : pre-condition violated ! ";

        cash=cash+money;
    }

    public boolean get(double money) {
        if (money>0 && cash>=money) {
            cash=cash-money;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public double count() {return cash;}

    public String toString(){
        return getClass().getName()+ "[cash = ]" + cash + "]";
    }
```

I'm having trouble calling the `put()` method outside of this class. How should my line of code be written for it to be called? I am using the variable name `money` to store the double, should I be doing that, or a different variable name altogether.

Comment: Can I recommend not using `assert` to validate your arguments? Use IllegalArgumentException instead. Presumably, this value comes from the user. `assert` should be used to detected programming errors, not user input errots. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Wallet walletObject = new Wallet();
walletObject.put(money);
```

Comment: @user3241910 wlc if it works for so mark it as correct

Comment: @user3241910 thats not the way I have given answer prior than him

Answer (score 5):

```
Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
wallet.put(money);
```

Comment: Thanks, probably a very newbie question :).

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say its:

```
double money = 123.123;
Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
wallet.put(money);
```

The variable name `money` within the class has absolutely no impact on how to call the method from the outside.
You can also call the method by

```
double val = 123.123;
Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
wallet.put(val);
```